# How can I make the jquery ui dialog opened even after page reload

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a webapp that store a layout,

And on its edit mode the user should click on the layout option inside a jquery ui dialog.

After the user choose the template that he/she want, the page will automatically reload.

I want the jquery-ui keep open even after the page was reloaded...

Hope it makes sense.

Hoping for your replys.

King Pangilinan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your whole page is being reloaded? If so you can't keep the dialog open but re-open it when your dom has been loaded. To do so you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("dialog_selector").dialog('open');
});
```

That just opens it. Now if you want to do it on a page reload you would have to embed this javascript code in some conditional ERB-code (if you're using ERB) or similar which meets your conditions...

Hope it's clear what I mean.